# Search by Email in lookup Field

Tags: lookup, administration, search-layout, parameterizedsearch

I have a standard case page layout, where contact is one of the lookup field.
Is it possible to search a contact by email in lookup field? (Like typing xxx@gmail.com in contact lookup field? As of now this is not retrieving any records but is there any setting to achieve this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is provided by default but the UX might not be exactly what you are looking for.

The fields that are searched by lookup are the same as those used in Global Search

Given I have a Contact with name = `Fred Fubar` and email address `ulyssesgrant@example.com`

- Go to a New Case, and click the Contact box
- Enter the full email address, full email address up to but excluding the @, or use a wildcard search like `ulysses*`, as shown below:

[image]

- Then click the dropdown row with the magnifying glass, you will see that the contact was located. Simply click on the Name field in the Contacts list and that Contact is now associated to the Case.ContactId field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to [Enable Enhanced Lookups](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_enhanced_lookup_enable.htm&type=5) using Setup-->QuickFind-->Search-->Search Settings and select contact.

[image]

Then navigate to case record and click on contact lookup and search with email and you should be able to see search results.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: per doc, this is Classic only